# How to pass the results of a custom query in Wordpress to another function

Tags: php, wordpress, function

This is I think really simple but I wasn't able to find an answer so far.

I am using a custom query in a function sc_start_custom_loop() which is fired via a custom shortcode.

```
function sc_start_custom_loop(){
    $args_assets = array(
        'post_type' => 'assets',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post__in' => $asset_ids,
        );

    $query_assets = new WP_Query($args_assets);
    if($query_assets->have_posts()) : while($query_assets->have_posts()) : $query_assets->the_post();

    output_custom_title();

    endwhile; else:
    _e('Sorry. No assets found!');
    endif; wp_reset_postdata();
}

function output_custom_title(){
    $ouput_title = '<p class="assets-title">'.$query_assets->post->post_title.'</p>';
    return $output_title;
}
```

However, $query_assets->post->post_title in output_custom_title() is empty.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function sc_start_custom_loop(){
    $args_assets = array(
        'post_type' => 'assets',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post__in' => $asset_ids,
        );

    $query_assets = new WP_Query($args_assets);
    if($query_assets->have_posts()) : while($query_assets->have_posts()) : $query_assets->the_post();

    echo output_custom_title($query_assets);

    endwhile; else:
    _e('Sorry. No assets found!');
    endif; wp_reset_postdata();
}

function output_custom_title($query_assets){
    $ouput_title = '<p class="assets-title">'.$query_assets->post->post_title.'</p>';
    return $output_title;
}
```